# Control Char Equivalent Trigger MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have two (many to one) tables. Student and Class table. Class table hold number of active students. If status of student is changed, trigger decrease one number of active student column.
So, I wrote a trigger like following :

```
CREATE TRIGGER decreaseNumOfActiveStudent AFTER UPDATE ON student
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
   DECLARE OLD_STATUS CHAR(1);

   SELECT STATUS INTO OLD_STATUS FROM STUDENT WHERE CLASS_ID = NEW.CLASS_ID;

   IF OLD_STATUS = '1' OR OLD_STATUS = 'O' THEN
      IF NEW.STATUS = '2' THEN
         UPDATE CLASS SET NUM_OF_ACTIVE_STUDENT = NUM_OF_ACTIVE_STUDENT - 1
         WHERE CLASS_ID = NEW.CLASS_ID;
      ENDIF;
   ENDIF;
END;
```

But, trigger does not update class table. I think, char control may be wrong. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql you can directly use new and old keyword to refer to the column data.

You can have the trigger as

```
delimiter //
create trigger decreaseNumOfActiveStudent after update on student
for each row
begin
 if new.status = '0' then
  update `class` set num_of_active_students = num_of_active_students-1
  where class_id = new.class_id ;
 end if;
end;//

delimiter ;
```

**TEST CASE**

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> create trigger decreaseNumOfActiveStudent after update on student
    -> for each row
    -> begin
    ->  if new.status = '0' then
    ->   update `class` set num_of_active_students = num_of_active_students-1
    ->   where class_id = new.class_id ;
    ->  end if;
    -> end;//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;
mysql> select * from student ;
+----+------+--------+----------+
| id | name | status | class_id |
+----+------+--------+----------+
|  1 | AAA  | 1      |        1 |
|  2 | BBB  | 0      |        1 |
|  3 | CCC  | 1      |        1 |
|  4 | DDD  | 1      |        1 |
|  5 | EEE  | 1      |        1 |
|  6 | FFF  | 1      |        2 |
+----+------+--------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from class ;
+----------+------------------------+
| class_id | num_of_active_students |
+----------+------------------------+
|        1 |                      4 |
|        2 |                      1 |
+----------+------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update student set status = '0' where id = 1 ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from class ;
+----------+------------------------+
| class_id | num_of_active_students |
+----------+------------------------+
|        1 |                      3 |
|        2 |                      1 |
+----------+------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note that you may need to add additional logic when the status is changed back to '1' then increase the value in `class` table and also if a record is deleted from student or a new entry is made to `student` table.

Comment: Your trigger decreases 1 value of num_of_active_students when every status changing request (status 0) for same student id. So, I need to know what old value of status is.

Comment: Yes you can use `old.status` something as `new.status = '0' and old.status <> '0'`

Comment: which old status for which student? I couldnot see old keyword. So, how can you use old keyword?

Comment: old should be accessible in after update, if you yse `old.status` it will contain the status of the student before it was updated.

Comment: Ok. I will try. Thanks @Abhik